# If $G \not \cong H$ and $K \not \cong H$ then is $G \not \cong K$?

Tags: abstract-algebra

If $G \not \cong H$ and $K \not \cong H$ then is $G \not \cong K$?, for groups $G,H,K$

We proved that If $G  \cong H$ and $K  \cong H$ then is $G\cong K$ I am wondering if this implies the title

for instance if $C_2 \times C_4 \not \cong C_8$ and $C_2 \times C_2 \times C_2 \not \cong C_8$ then is $C_2 \times C_4 \not \cong C_2 \times C_2 \times C_2$?

Comment: What if $G=K$...?

Comment: If $G=K$ you have it

Comment: what about $G = K$

Comment: Take any group $G$, take any group $K$ that is isomorphic to it; take any group $H$ that is *not* isomorphic to it and that's a counterexample.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Suppose $G\ncong H$, so that $H\ncong G$.  Does this implies that $G\ncong G$ holds?

(Note that I simply replaced your $K$ with $G$ here.)

Comment: I guess not - but for $G \not = K$ would it hold? I have edited with an example

Comment: Why was this downvoted?

Comment: @sarah_morgan1 Just take something that is isomorphic to $G$ but unequal to it (like $K=G\oplus \{1\}$).

Comment: Thanks, I guess I just thought that because I proved that $C_2 \times C_4 \not \cong C_8$ and $C_2 \times C_2 \times C_2 \not \cong C_8$ then I thought $C_2 \times C_4 \not \cong C_2 \times C_2 \times C_2$ but I guess I will find another way to prove it is not isomorphic.

Comment: @sarah_morgan1 Yep, you'll have to find another way.  Feel free to post another question specifically about showing they aren't isomorphic though (hint: is there a degree 4 element in $C_2\times C_2\times C_2$?)

Comment: I do not understand the downvotes.

Comment: @whacka I think people might have thought I simply copied the comments on the question, though if they'd have looked at the time stamps they'd have seen I posted this at approximately the same time as the comments.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: Is this true for numbers and equality?